# Why different smartphones show different things of positioning?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, wifi

There are 3 smartphones:Aplcatel Pop4 (6.0.1), Sony Z (5.1.1), WelyFox (6.0.1).

Code: I am getting coordinates via WiFi and GPS separately and put results into different TextViews. All necessary privileges are set.

AlcatelPop4: gets data via GPS reciever only (and place them into GPS textview) and being near the window or outdoor. No coordinates via WIFI.

Sony Z: rapidly finds coordinates via WiFi. GPS works outdoor and near windows as it should with good accuracy.

WelyFox: Find coordinates rapidly as Sony's Wifi BUT they are obtained via GPS and put into GPS textView. No coordinates via WiFi given, however the accuracy is wifi like..

Actually I need to understand, how to get coordinates indoor?

Why are these devices acting differently when running identical code?
Code is completely copy pasted from google manuals.
I will be grateful for getting a mentor in these questions of GPS and google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, GPS is a hardware, mounted on a motherboard of mobile.
This hardware is manufactured by many manufacturers and they differ in quality..

Hence they manufacturer is responsible for the GPS positioning.

How GPS works exactly..?

GPS will send a message to Satellites to get his position. when more than 3 Satelite response him with same location then it will consider as accurate location and show us latitude and longitue.

Now, its totally depend on your GPS hardware. that's why you are getting different results on different devices.

Hope this will helpful!!!

Comment: Thank you for a response, though I knew the theoretical aspect before. I thought that some of this may be related to different hardware, but not so much and for example google maps works perfectly on alcatel pop4 via GPS and WIFI... so what's wrong with my app, I do not understand.